# Vector Drawable inside Layer-list is stretching

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

When I use a layer-list with a vector-drawable inside, it works fine on API 23+ but not prior.

I have enabled `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` and `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`, yet the drawable is very stretched.

[image: Left is Oreo 26 and right is Lollipop 21]

Left is Oreo 26 and right is Lollipop 21

This is the drawable

```xml
<layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <stroke android:width="0.9dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
                    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
                    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_drawable" android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:left="18dp" />
        </layer-list>
```

And this is where the drawable is applied

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_dropdown_background"
        android:popupElevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/citySpinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />
```

It's inside a ConstraintLayout, but I can't post the whole layout file.

What can I do to fix the stretching Pre API 23?
Would creating the whole layer-list in code be any different?

**Edit:** I did try it before, but forgot to add it.
I did try the following xml

```xml
<layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <stroke android:width="0.9dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
                    <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
                    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:left="18dp">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/arrow_drawable" android:gravity="center_vertical|left"/>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
```

But this made the app crash as soon as it starts saying `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/spinner_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700de` Which is probably not alot of sense. And this is what the preview in Android Studio shows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `layer-list` drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) states:

> All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View, by default. Thus, placing your images in a layer list at different positions might increase the size of the View and some images scale as appropriate. To avoid scaling items in the list, use a `<bitmap>` element inside the `<item>` element to specify the drawable and define the gravity to something that does not scale, such as `"center"`.

Try this out:

```
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="0.9dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="18dp">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_drawable"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This creates an exception on launch, and also, the editor's preview shows an error image

Comment: What's the exception? What error does android studio show in the preview (if you click on the red ! icon in the top-right)?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I wrote `android:drawable` when I should have written `android:src`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Well I was stupid enough to forget which I tried, drawable or src. Anyways, either of them makes the same exception `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/spinner_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700de` Preview doesn't say what the problem is, it just shows an error image. I'll update the question

Comment: @AhmadSattout ah, probably an issue with loading vector resources